# Sharepoint 2013 - Permission to only allow for the document creator to EDIT the document

Tags: sharepoint-2013

Is there a way to control permissions on a SharePoint so that the user that uploads a document to a Document Library is the only one that can edit or delete that file?  I want other users to be able to open the file, but as read-only and not checked out (I don't care if they save it to their computer and make changes to a local copy).

I guess a summary of this would be a permission group that allows everyone to ADD and DELETE files, but only the creator of the file added can check out and EDIT.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could create event receiver for this library, when file got uploaded, break permission inherit and assign unique permission for author and others(maybe a group).

Here is sample code from [technet](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/9877857f-83d0-4065-8db7-22474d6bdcfa/break-item-permission-on-itemadding?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

namespace SurveyPermissionsMgr
{
    class ThreeMonthSurveyPermissionsMgr : SPItemEventReceiver
    {
        public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
                SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                {
                    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(properties.WebUrl))
                    {
                        site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                        {
                            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                            SPListItem myItem = web.Lists[properties.ListId].GetItemById(properties.ListItem.ID); //  GET LIST OBJECT FROM SPWEB, NOT EVENT PROPERTIES

                            myItem.BreakRoleInheritance(false);

                            this.DisableEventFiring();
                            myItem.Update();

                            SPMember member = web.SiteGroups["My Group"];
                            SPPrincipal principal = (SPPrincipal)member;
                            SPRoleDefinition roledefinition = web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Contributor);
                            SPRoleAssignment myRoleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(principal);
                            myRoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(roledefinition);
                            myItem.RoleAssignments.Add(myRoleAssignment);

                            string managerstring = myItem["Manager Account Id"].ToString();
                            SPUser manager = web.EnsureUser(managerstring);

                            myItem["Manager"] = manager;

                            SPPrincipal managerprincipal = (SPPrincipal)manager;
                            SPRoleDefinition managerroledefinition = web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Reader);
                            SPRoleAssignment ManagerRoleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(managerprincipal);
                            ManagerRoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(managerroledefinition);
                            myItem.RoleAssignments.Add(ManagerRoleAssignment);

                            string associatestring = myItem["Author"].ToString();
                            int userid = Convert.ToInt32(associatestring.Substring(0, associatestring.IndexOf(";#")));
                            SPUser associate = web.AllUsers.GetByID(userid);
                            SPPrincipal associateprincipal = (SPPrincipal)associate;
                            SPRoleDefinition associateroledefinition = web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Reader);
                            SPRoleAssignment AssociateRoleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(associateprincipal);
                            AssociateRoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(associateroledefinition);
                            myItem.RoleAssignments.Add(AssociateRoleAssignment);

                            myItem.Update();
                            this.EnableEventFiring();
                            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                            site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;

                            //Handle messaging
                            StringDictionary dict = new StringDictionary();
                            dict.Add("to", manager.Email);
                            dict.Add("from", "us@you.com");
                            dict.Add("subject", "bla bla bla");
                            string msgbody = "bla bla bla";
                            SPUtility.SendEmail(web, dict, msgbody);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```